# Read mutiple html links with rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to scrape information from IMDB but I encouter some problem that I don't how to fix it. I success to scrape the title, year, rating etc but when I try to scrape the cast name, I first need to go into the each movie link and get to the full cast page from there to scrape.

read_html function won't allow me to read mutiple html and I am not sure what other function I can use.

Here is my code

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

link = "https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?title_type=feature&num_votes=25000,&genres=adventure&sort=user_rating,desc"
page = read_html(link)

name = page %>% html_nodes(".lister-item-header a") %>% html_text()
year = page %>% html_nodes(".text-muted.unbold") %>% html_text()
rating = page %>% html_nodes(".ratings-imdb-rating strong") %>% html_text()
synopsis = page %>% html_nodes(".ratings-bar+ .text-muted") %>% html_text()

movie_links = page %>% html_nodes(".lister-item-header a") %>%
  html_attr("href") %>% paste("https://www.imdb.com", ., sep="")

castlink <- gsub("\\?ref_=adv_li_tt", "fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm", movie_links)
cast_page <-read_htmls(castlink)
```

I created the castlink for all 50 movies cast link in the 'castlink'

Thank you for explaining to me. I appreciate you!

Answer (score 1):

You could put the cast page reading in a loop:

```
casts <- vector(mode="list", length=length(castlink))
for(i in 1:length(castlink)){
  cast_page <- read_html(castlink[i])  
  casts[[i]] <- cast_page %>% 
    html_nodes(css=".cast_list > tr > td:nth-child(2) > a:nth-child(1)") %>% 
    html_text() %>% 
    trimws() %>% 
    gsub("\\n", "", .)
}
```